# Вопрос по работе с изображениями

Tags: php

Есть [функция](http://bit.ly/Mv8ANg) для изменения размера изображений.
Всё хорошо вот только при обработке png, если картинка была сохранена без фона, изменённая картинка выходит с чёрным фоном.
Возможно ли как-то сделать чтоб фон был белым?

**UPD**

[Проблема решена](http://code.wen.ru/KUsXCvzkf)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону функции [imagesavealpha()](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.imagesavealpha.html). Только, если не ошибаюсь, там что-то не все гладко с ней было.

Comment: @Deonis Эмм... В функции, ссылка на которую указана в вопросе, нет этой ((imagesavealpha()) функции... Но, спасибо за совет. Попробую что-то с ней попробовать...

Comment: @Deonis Что-то не получается ничего... нЕ мог бы ты подправить функцию?..